# Keras Python Multi Image Input shape error

Tags: python, machine-learning, neural-network, keras, conv-neural-network

I am trying to teach myself to build a CNN that takes more than one image as an input. Since the dataset I created to test this is large and in the long run I hope to solve a problem involving a very large dataset, I am using a generator to read images into arrays which I am passing to Keras Model's `fit_generator` function.

When I run my generator in isolation it works fine, and produces outputs of the appropriate shape. It yields a tuple containing two entries, the first of which has shape `(4, 100, 100, 1)` and the second of which has shape `(4, )`.

Reading about multiple input Keras CNNs has given me the impression that this is the right format for a generator for a 4 input CNN that is identifying which of the 4 inputs contains an image.

However, when I run the code I get:

```
"ValueError: Error when checking input: expected input_121 to have 4 dimensions, but got array with shape (100, 100, 1)"
```

I've been searching for a solution for some time now and I suspect that the problem lies in getting my `(100, 100, 1)` shape arrays to be sent to the Inputs as `(None, 100, 100, 1)` shape arrays.

But when I tried to modify the output of my generator I get an error about having dimension `5`, which makes sense as an error because the output of the generator should have the form `X, y = [X1, X2, X3, X4], [a, b, c, d]`, where `Xn` has shape `(100, 100, 1)`, and a/b/c/d are numbers.

Here is the code:

https://gist.github.com/anonymous/d283494aee982fbc30f3b52f2a6f422c

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are creating a list of arrays in your generator with the wrong dimensions.

If you want the correct shape, reshape individual images to have the 4 dimensions: (`n_samples`, `x_size`, `y_size`, `n_bands`) your model will work. In your case you should reshape your images to `(1, 100, 100, 1)`.

At the end stack them with `np.vstack`. The generator will yield an array of shape `(4, 100, 100, 1)`.

**Check if this adapted code works**

```
def input_generator(folder, directories):

    Streams = []
    for i in range(len(directories)):
        Streams.append(os.listdir(folder + "/" + directories[i]))
        for j in range(len(Streams[i])):
            Streams[i][j] = "Stream" + str(i + 1) + "/" + Streams[i][j]   
        Streams[i].sort()


    length = len(Streams[0])
    index = 0
    while True:
        X = []
        y = np.zeros(4)
        for Stream in Streams:
            image = load_img(folder + '/' + Stream[index], grayscale = True)
            array = img_to_array(image).reshape((1,100,100,1))
            X.append(array)
        y[int(Stream[index][15]) - 1] = 1
        index += 1
        index = index % length
        yield np.vstack(X), y
```