# Getting an error with a multi-input Keras model related to the input dimension

Tags: python, numpy, tensorflow, keras, conv-neural-network

I have a multi input Keras model. Here the inputs:

```
[<tf.Tensor 'input_1:0' shape=(None, 256, 256, 3) dtype=float32>,
 <tf.Tensor 'input_2:0' shape=(None, 256, 256, 3) dtype=float32>,
 <tf.Tensor 'input_3:0' shape=(None, 256, 256, 3) dtype=float32>,
 <tf.Tensor 'input_4:0' shape=(None, 256, 256, 3) dtype=float32>]
```

And here the input shape of the model :

```
[(None, 256, 256, 3),
 (None, 256, 256, 3),
 (None, 256, 256, 3),
 (None, 256, 256, 3)]
```

The training data shape is as follows :

```
(4, 422, 256, 256, 3)
4 = number of inputs (consist of appended arrays together).
422 = number of training images in each input.
256, 256, 3 = shape of the images
```

When I call the `fit` function:

```
model.fit(train_x, train_y, validation_split=0.20, epochs=5, batch_size=3)
```

The following error occured:

> ValueError: Input 0 of layer conv1_pad_0 is incompatible with the layer: expected ndim=4, found ndim=5. Full shape received: [3, 422, 256, 256, 3]

I have tried the solution given in [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44399299/keras-python-multi-image-input-shape-error), but I got a mismatch in cardinality.

> ValueError: Data cardinality is ambiguous:

I have tried passing the train data like bellow and it worked:

```
model.fit([train_x[0], train_x[1], train_x[2], train_x[3]], train_y, validation_split=0.20, epochs=5, batch_size=3)
```

Now If I want to scale my model to 20 inputs the above line of code will be problematique.

**Update:**

The model are based on the pretrained **ResNet50**, all inputs are a resnet50 without the top layers and begin with the following three layers :

```
input_1_0 (InputLayer)        [(None, 256, 256, 3) 0  
conv1_pad_0 (ZeroPadding2D)   (None, 262, 262, 3)  0           input_1_0[0][0]
conv1_conv_0 (Conv2D)         (None, 128, 128, 64) 9472        conv1_pad_0[0][0]
```

The data for training/testing the model is processed as follows:

```
for row in np.array(tmp_data):
        row = images_preprocessing(row) # Depends on the model used
        train_x, test_x, train_y, test_y = split_data(row, target) # Here the train_test_split is used
        
        train_X.append(train_x)
        test_X.append(test_x)
        train_Y.append(train_y)
        test_Y.append(test_y)
```

Comment: What are the first two layers of your network?

Comment: @ChrisSchmitz I have updated the post with what you asked.

Comment: Could you also show the code in which you define them? Also which dimension of your training data is total nr. of examples / batch size?

Comment: @ChrisSchmitz I updated the post. What do you mean by number of examples?

Comment: The training data shape is as follows : (4, 422, 256, 256, 3) . What does 4 and 422 represent in your input ? the input to pretrained ResNet50 should have 4d.

Comment: The 4 represents the number of input. Instead of passing each input individually, I appended all the input in an array and pass it to the model as the final model will have 20 input. If I pass 20 input individually it will look a bit messy. As for the 422, it represents the number of training images.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try

```
train_x_list = [tf.squeeze(tx) for tx in tf.split(train_x, num_or_size_splits=train_x.shape[0], axis=0)]
```

it will produce a list of tensors with training data split along dimension 0. Then use your second solution, feeding the list to `fit()`.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, it worked.  Could you explain if possible why this worked and not a simple list of arrays? Also, I'm training multiple models in a loop, the first one executed perfectly, but the second one, it  generated this error : `tensorflow.python.framework.errors_impl.InternalError: Failed copying input tensor from /job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/device:CPU:0 to /job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/device:GPU:0 in order to run Split: Dst tensor is not initialized. [Op:Split] name: split`

Comment: you're welcome. I just shown a way to split your input data. A list  of np arrays will likely be OK too.

Comment: your other error could be a memory issue: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37313818/tensorflow-dst-tensor-is-not-initialized

Comment: I'm struggling with another issue, could you take a look at my previous post : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64118599/getting-the-runtimeerror-unable-to-create-link-name-already-exists-with-tenso